# Storage type used in app like Instagram

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instagram

I want to make an app like Instagram but the problem is where to store all text and images data, I have used Instagram when there is no connectivity available then app will show the last feeds even when app is freshly openend (not from background). It uses core data or sqlite.

Comment: The type of storage used is irrelevant. Pick whatever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not known what Instagram uses. Use whatever you feel most comfortable with. Anything is possible with any storage technology, although some might fit better than others. Also, regarding your question on "core data or sqlite", you can use Core Data with an SQLite database as a backend (way easier than accessing raw SQL). You can also use other backends with Core Data: binary and XML.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a scaling presentation from instagram a little while back where they talk how they started, using what and then how they approached the challenges.

See the link: http://www.scribd.com/doc/89025069/Mike-Krieger-Instagram-at-the-Airbnb-tech-talk-on-Scaling-Instagram

Hope this helps.